# How to send and recive messages from JS WebSocket to Java Server?

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, websocket, server

I know how to code a java server for java clients but I am starting with Js coding and i definetly do not understand the way its sockets work. I am trying to use a normal TCP server in Java but i am just recieving part of the messeage header from Js but not the message. My code is probably just wrong so I would love if someone just send me and example of a JS client with a Java server and some ramdom String transactions.I am attaching my code just to make you suffer :)

`var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080"); socket.send("hola");`

````
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket= new ServerSocket(8080);
            ClientHandler clientHandler;

            while (true){
                Socket socket= serverSocket.accept();
                clientHandler= new ClientHandler(socket);
                clientHandler.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class ClientHandler extends Thread{
        Socket socket; InputStream in; OutputStream out; BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket){
            try {
                this.socket= socket;
                in= socket.getInputStream();
                out= socket.getOutputStream();
                bufferedInputStream= new BufferedInputStream(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress()+"Connected successfully");

            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
                System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many problem within your code. Any way your current problem is Server implemented a **TCP** server but client use a **WebSocket** which is a protocol on top of **TCP** so you must handle that protocol too. You have to implement http web socket protocol by yourself or use **Netty** or other libs that implemented it.